# HLS playback problems

Tags: java, http-live-streaming, ant-media-server-sdk

Using Enterprise Edition 1.9.1 official AMI on AWS.

#### Scenario:

Ant Media Server application is configured to use ABR with 360, 480, 720 resolutions.

The player-side code polls the HLS stream URL waiting for the stream to start.

#### Expected behavior:

1. When the stream is not live, respond with 404 error
2. When the stream goes live, respond with the m3u8 containing all defined resolutions

#### Actual behavior:

1. When the stream is not live, the HTTP status returned for the m3u8 is 200 but the contents of the response is a 404 not found page.
2. When the live stream starts, the m3u8 received contains only one resolution (I think, it's random - can be any of the pre-defined):

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=0,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
5e820545bd53c64aca9c57c1_720p.m3u8
```

3. If I request the m3u8 in a few seconds after the incomplete one, I receive the complete m3u8 with all defined resolutions:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=680704,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
5e820545bd53c64aca9c57c1_360p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1072360,RESOLUTION=854x480,CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
5e820545bd53c64aca9c57c1_480p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1409432,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
5e820545bd53c64aca9c57c1.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2263000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
5e820545bd53c64aca9c57c1_720p.m3u8
```

#### Workaround:

Currently I am resolving this by parsing the contents of the response:

- If it contains 404 error, continue polling
- If the m3u8 is shorter than 6 lines (empiric value), continue polling
- When a correct m3u8 arrives, start the player

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appeared to be a bug that has been fixed in v2.0.
After the upgrade everything works as documented.